# How do I use wildcards when replacing a hotstring in AutoHotkey?

Tags: lua, autohotkey

I want to replace 'th' with þ automatically using AutoHotkey, but when þ is part of another word, my code does nothing. My script is:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

::th::þ
```

Answer (score 0):

These are [options for Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotstrings.htm#Options):

```
; T: the auto-replacement string will be sent in Text mode 
; *: the hotstring will trigger without special ending character 
; ?: the hotstring will also trigger inside other words - not only at the beginning of a new word

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

:T*?:th::þ
```